# Заменить флаг s в парсере BB кода

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Всем привет! Столкнулся с проблемой отсутствия поддержки флага **s** на Firefox 68. Обновить браузер возможности нет. В проекте использую библиотеку js-bbcode-parser, в которой есть такое место:

```
setCodes(codes) {
    this.codes = Object.keys(codes).map(function (regex) {
        const replacement = codes[regex];

        return {
            regexp:      new RegExp(regex, 'igms'),
            replacement: replacement
        };
    }, this);

    return this;
}
```

Как можно заменить этот флаг s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо `.` можно использовать `[^]`.

### Разбор

Конструкция `[^123]` совпадает со всем, кроме 1, 2 или 3, т.е. обратное действие к `[123]`.
Т. е. `[^]` – это "всё, кроме ничего".

### Что такое s

Флаг s означает, что точка может совпадать с `\n`, т. е. новой строкой.

### Правки в коде

```js
setCodes(codes) {
    this.codes = Object.keys(codes).map(function (regex) {
        regex = regex.replace(/\./g, "[^]");
        const replacement = codes[regex];

        return {
            regexp:      new RegExp(regex, 'igm'),
            replacement: replacement
        };
    }, this);

    return this;
}
```